# Passing an object from React to Express and creating a new Airtable record

Tags: reactjs, express, airtable

I’m having trouble passing an object from React to Express, and then creating an airtable record in Express.

In react, i am sending an http request to Express via:

```
finalSubmit() {
  const airtableObj = {
    title: 'hi',
  }
  fetch('api/submit',{
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(airtableObj),
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
  })
}
```

My Express code is:

```
app.post('/api/submit', jsonParser, async (req, res) => { 
    const newStudy = JSON.stringify(req.body);   
    await console.log(newStudy); 
    table.create(newStudy, function(err, record) {  
        if (err) {console.log(err); res.json(err)} else {console.log(record), res.json('Success!')}
    });   
})
```

However, I keep getting errors back from the airtable api. IF I replace the 4th line of my express code with:

```
table.create({“title”:“hi”}
```

instead of

```
table.create(newStudy)
```

, everything works fine. It seems like this should work according to the airtable documentationt... (https://airtable.com/api). Is there something I am doing wrong with how I am manipulating my data in and out of JSON?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be happening because you're calling `JSON.stringify(req.body)`, which you don't need to do.

`table.create` takes an object, not a string, so you'll want to do something like this:

```
const newStudy = req.body;
table.create(newStudy, function(err, record) {  
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, not sure if it's a very good one tho...

```
app.post('/api/submit', jsonParser, async (req, res) => { 
    table.create({
        "title": `${req.body.post0.title}`} ...
```

Comment: Hmm seems like you have an extra parameter in your req.body here.

Comment: ah, yes i am getting my parameters from my state in react, which has nested objects